# NPM Install pre-release versions for peer dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, lerna, semantic-versioning

We have a mono-repository using lerna. On every pull request, we would like to create a pre-release version and publish it.

Demo Project for better understanding => [react-lerna-demo](https://github.com/keth-dev/react-lerna-demo/tree/feature/pr-version/packages)

Package structure:

- util-lib
- shared-ui --> util-lib (peer-dep)
- web-app --> shared-lib & util-lib

Normal releases works just fine. But pre-release has the following problem.

- When util-lib has a change, it would have version like `4.0.6-1b596d6.0`
- shared-ui has a peer dep version like `^4.0.0`
- Web-App is then changed to `"@keth-dev/lerna-demo-util-lib": "4.0.6-1b596d6.0"` (see [changes](https://github.com/keth-dev/react-lerna-demo/pull/1/files#diff-04b9a7a074c0e493e7a8afd80bc911f886e19843e7e3fc23201bdc29b8f87a78R21-R22)

This worked before npm v7. But now it throws an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @keth-dev/lerna-demo-web-app@4.0.5
npm ERR! Found: @keth-dev/lerna-demo-util-lib@4.0.6-1b596d6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@keth-dev/lerna-demo-util-lib
npm ERR!   @keth-dev/lerna-demo-util-lib@"4.0.6-1b596d6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @keth-dev/lerna-demo-util-lib@"^4.0.0" from @keth-dev/lerna-demo-shared-ui@4.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@keth-dev/lerna-demo-shared-ui
npm ERR!   @keth-dev/lerna-demo-shared-ui@"4.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --no-strict-peer-deps, --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Build details => https://github.com/keth-dev/react-lerna-demo/runs/5545142338?check_suite_focus=true

Are there any solutions to support dynamic pre-release versions without `legacy-peer-deps` flag?

`semver` package provides an option `includePrerelease` to suppress the strict version match.

> If a version has a prerelease tag (for example, 1.2.3-alpha.3) then it will only be allowed to satisfy comparator sets if at least one comparator with the same [major, minor, patch] tuple also has a prerelease tag.

Is there a way to pass this flag while installing using npm?

[image: semver experiment]

Comment: I have the same problem with our shared company internal NPM package. Can I ask you how you solved this issue (if you did)?

Comment: It could be a better idea to raise this with npm support.

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents here... (might not be an ideal solution)

In order to support dynamic pre-releases that are referenced in peer-dependencies of another dependency without using `--legacy-peer-deps`, I ended up using the `overrides` property of `package.json`.

Here is what the [official doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) says about `overrides`:

> If you need to make specific changes to dependencies of your
> dependencies, for example replacing the version of a dependency with a
> known security issue, replacing an existing dependency with a fork, or
> making sure that the same version of a package is used everywhere,
> then you may add an override.
>
> Overrides provide a way to replace a package in your dependency tree with another version, or another package entirely. These changes
> can be scoped as specific or as vague as desired.

For instance,

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "foo": "1.O.0", // has a peer-dependency to bar@^1.0.0
        "bar": "1.1.0-pre.1" // would normaly fail as bar@1.1.0-pre.1 is not part of bar@^1.0.0 according to NPM implementation of semver
    },
    "overrides": {
        "bar": "$bar" // the override is defined as a reference to the dependency
    }
}
```

Again, that might not be the ideal solution but it works.

However keep in mind that having the override disables the peer dependency validity checks for the `bar` package completely.

I plan on adapting my tooling in order to prevent `overrides` during a release build for instance.

Any comment on why I should not do this is welcomed.

Note that there has been discussions last year about this exact issue in the NPM RFC but nothing came out of it: https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/397